# How to trim username from email id in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

How to drop everything after `@` in email id in terraform

```
  count                    = length(local.admin_users)
  username                 = "${trimspace(local.admin_users[count.index])}_default"
```

It gives me `test@gmail.com_default`

I want `test_default`

How can this be accomplished in terraform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`split`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/split) the `admin_user` based on `@` character and use its first part:

```
username = "${split("@", trimspace(local.admin_users[count.index]))[0]}_default"
```